# "Could not resolve host: github.com" when trying to get Julia packages

Tags: 16.04, networking, curl, github, julia-lang

I'm sorry if I'm noob on computer science but I am with a few problems when trying to download packages for Julia language. I have installed the version 0.6 on a Ubuntu 16.04.3 and I can reach into the REPL terminal. But when I put the command: `Pkg.add.(~some packages here from github~)` I get the error `ERROR: Cannot clone ~Package X~ from https://github.com/path-of-package.jl.git. curl error: Could not resolve host: github.com`. 
I've read a lot of foruns about this and tried a many things, but I've no idea what to do to solve this. Someone please help me!!

Comment: Are you using a proxy, VPN, corporate/university network? Can you access other websites with curl?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know what you mean with proxy, VPN or curl. But no, I'm not in a corporate/university network

Comment: OK, can you access websites in a web browser?

Comment: Yes, on a browser I can access everything